# Load Data from Synchronized data extension to data extensions by SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

I am trying to get Synchronized data extensions data to Data extensions in salesforce marketing cloud, I need a custom field from campaigns Synchronized data extensions.

I made a query as 
select Id, Name, Status, Type, IsActive, [Campaign_Code_in_Marketing_Cloud__c]  from Campaign_Salesforce

In the target Data Extension, I can see all the values except for Campaign_Code_in_Marketing_Cloud__c.

Campaign_Code_in_Marketing_Cloud__c is a custom field in CRM, can anyone tell me the way to get the custom fields to Data Extensions.

Thanks

Comment: You wrote that you can't see the value for your custom field. Do you mean that the field is missing in your target data extension or is it not populated by the query?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select the checkbox for the custom field in **Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized**.

1. Click the **Campaign Object**
2. Click **Edit Fields**
3. Click the checkbox for your custom field to make sure it is being synchronized.

Comment: Hi Jackson, The custom field is synchronized and I am able to see the value of custom filed in Synchronized data extension but it is being blank in Data Extension.

Comment: Make sure the datatype and length in the data extension matches that of the synchronized data extension